# How can I make the onchange event work for the text input box update by the javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know how can I make the onchange event work for the text input box update by the javascript/Jquery?

Example:

Instead of manually key in the text into the input box, I will insert the value into the text box by using jquery as below. Any way that the onchange event will work once the value been change in the text box by jquery? Any way I can make it work?

**HTML:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <input type="text" ID="test" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(".test").val("ABC");


$('.test').change(function () {
    alert('hello')
});
```

Comment: onChange event is for textarea and select controls. Use the onblur event.

Comment: @jeff *The `change` event is fired for `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` elements when a change to the element's value is committed by the user.* [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change)

Comment: @rink.attendant.6, I agree but as MDN states 'Different browsers do not always agree whether a change event should be fired for certain types of interaction.' So I tend to ignore the onchange event for input types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) it:

```
$('.test').change(function () {
    alert('hello');
});

$(".test").val("ABC");
$('.test').trigger('change');
```